# How can I ORDER BY according to some boolean logic?

Tags: sql, sorting, boolean

Say I have columns 'a' and 'b'.  A record is deemed 'ready' if `!a || b`.  How can I sort by this ready condition?  I'm really rusty with SQL and I can't recall what would have been the best way to do this.  My guess is that I would be able to add a column with the boolean result and then sort by that column, but I've tried searching and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Some support Booleans in ways others do not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
order by case when !a || b then 0 else 1 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
ORDER BY (!a || b) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just want all rows where !a or b is true first?  If so order by !a and then by b.